# How to recognize scrollbar and scroll up/down using Selenium2, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, scrollbar, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am testing an app using  C# , Selenium2. Can any one suggest what is code for the scrollbar event,  so that it recognizes and scrolls down/up using firefox driver.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be scroll to relevant item

```
try
{
    System.Drawing.Point point = ((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sLocator))).LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
}
catch (Exception)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to have WebDriver scroll for you, but you can always controll the scrolling with JavaScript or jQuery...

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("scroll(0,200);");
```

Just make sure jQuery is referenced in the page you're on.  In this case, make sure to have the scroll function in your page.  If it's not there, this won't work.

Comment: thank you for the reply , but reply in C# would be much aprreciated.

Comment: That actually is in C#. The "ExecuteScript" method transfers the code to the javascript for the browser to use.  It is how I had to perform scrolling in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ScrollDown(WebDriver driver)
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scroll(0, 350);");
}
```

Based on window size change/increase argument value.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a `height` parameter, and then replacing the argument to `ExecuteScript` from a constant string to `string.Format("window.scroll(0, {0});", height)`

Answer (score 0):

This is java code to scroll :

```
//Scroll Bar code For move Upwards
Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.className("mCSB_dragger_bar"));
int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown1 = 1500;
for (int i=10;i<1000;i=i+numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown1){
        try{
    // this causes a gradual drag of the scroll bar, 10 units at a time
    dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown1).release().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
        }catch(Exception e1){}
```